# Calculate total time between earliest and latest visit for all visits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am storing user's visits in the following table (with sample data):

| id | user_id | page | visit_id | page_visit_created_at | page_visit_last_activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | page1 | 11 | 2023-06-21 16:56:13.950 | 2023-06-21 16:58:23.823 |
| 2 | 2 | page1 | 12 | 2023-06-21 17:36:45.550 | 2023-06-21 17:50:23.553 |
| 3 | 1 | page2 | 11 | 2023-06-21 17:01:12.120 | 2023-06-21 17:04:51.122 |
| 4 | 3 | page1 | 14 | 2023-06-21 18:02:13.421 | 2023-06-21 18:09:11.111 |
| 5 | 3 | page3 | 15 | 2023-06-21 18:23:51.383 | 2023-06-21 18:31:11.347 |
| 6 | 1 | page1 | 16 | 2023-06-22 13:10:11.223 | 2023-06-22 13:15:10.111 |

And I need to calculate the total activity time for each user, which means to sum the time between `page_visit_created_at` and `page_visit_last_activity` for each user, per `visit_id`.

In the example above, the user with `user_id` 1 visited `page1` and `page2` at the same visit session, that's why they have the same `visit_id`, so I need to minimum `page_visit_created_at` for `visit_id` 11, which is `2023-06-21 16:56:13.950` from row 1, and the latest `page_visit_last_activity` which is `2023-06-21 17:04:51.122`.

He also visited `page1` with a different `visit_id` (visit 16) and once only so the minimum is `2023-06-22 13:10:11.223` and max is `2023-06-22 13:15:10.111`

so the total would be the sum of the two.

The following query doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, visit_id, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(page_visit_created_at), MAX(page_visit_last_activity))) 
FROM 
    my_table
GROUP BY 
    user_id, visit_id
```

I get this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Comment: Why do you need the `SUM` *and* the `MIN` and `MAX` here? If you want to `SUM` the time between the start and end times for each row, the `MIN`/`MAX` aren't needed. If you just want the time between the earlier start and the lastest end, then there's no need for the `SUM`.

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know how to get the minimum of each `visit_id` when I GROUP BY beacuse I lose that data (I don't GROUP BY the date columns), so I thought using `MIN` and `MAX` will give me that data (clearly not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that using aggregate functions within aggregate functions is not permitted. one option is to calculate time spent per visit using `min()` and `max()` separately in a subquery then apply the aggregate function `sum()` on this dataset :

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(time_per_visit) as total
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, visit_id, 
     DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(page_visit_created_at), MAX(page_visit_last_activity)) as time_per_visit 
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY user_id, visit_id
) AS s
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: You beat me by two minutes.

Comment: :D Great job on being so quick too!

Comment: thanks, was hard choosing between your answers, but at the end of the day, there can only be one answer to rule them all (and I assume @TheImpaler gave the credit to SelVazi with this comment)

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate in two phases. For example:

```
select user_id, sum(session) as total
from (
  select
    user_id, visit_id, 
    datediff(second, min(page_visit_created_at), 
      max(page_visit_last_activity)) as session
  from t
  group by user_id, visit_id
) x
group by user_id
```